# No member named 'addQueryItem' in 'QUrl' - Convert Qt 4.7 to 5.8

Tags: c++, qt, qurl

I need to **convert Qt legacy code from 4.7 to 5.8**, I have a compilation error in Qt Creator 4.2.1 Clang 7.0(Apple) 64bit.

**Looking in .cpp file**

```
QList<QByteArray> priceGetterTSP::downloadFile(const QString &symbol_, int beginDate_, int endDate_)
{
   QNetworkAccessManager manager;
   QEventLoop loop;
   QNetworkRequest request(QUrl("http://www.fedsmith.com/tsp/csv.dailyfund.db.php"));
   QByteArray data;
   QUrl params;
   QDate beginQDate = QDate::fromJulianDay(beginDate_);
   QDate endQDate = QDate::fromJulianDay(endDate_);

QString properCaseSymbol = symbol_.left(3).append(symbol_.right(symbol_.length() - 3).toLower());
  params.addQueryItem("fund", properCaseSymbol);
  params.addQueryItem("frommonth", QString::number(beginQDate.month()));
  params.addQueryItem("fromday", QString::number(beginQDate.day()));
  params.addQueryItem("fromyear", QString::number(beginQDate.year()));
  params.addQueryItem("tomonth", QString::number(endQDate.month()));
  params.addQueryItem("today", QString::number(endQDate.day()));
  params.addQueryItem("toyear", QString::number(endQDate.year()));
  data.append(params.toString());
  data.remove(0,1);

QNetworkReply *reply = manager.post(request, data);
QObject::connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));

loop.exec();

QList<QByteArray> lines;
if (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError)
    lines = reply->readAll().split('\n');

delete reply;
return lines;
}
```

**Looking at the Top of the .cpp**

```
#include "priceGetterTSP.h"

#include <QString>
#include <QList>
#include <QByteArray>
#include <QUrl>
#include <QDate>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QNetworkRequest>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QEventLoop>
#include <historicalPrices.h>
```

ERROR in .cpp

../src/prices/priceGetterTSP.cpp:86:12: **error: no member named 'addQueryItem' in 'QUrl'**
    params.addQueryItem("fund", properCaseSymbol);
    ~~~~~~ ^
../src/prices/priceGetterTSP.cpp:87:12: **error: no member named 'addQueryItem' in 'QUrl'**
    params.addQueryItem("frommonth", QString::number(beginQDate.month()));
    ~~~~~~ ^
../src/prices/priceGetterTSP.cpp:88:12: error: no member named 'addQueryItem' in 'QUrl'
    params.addQueryItem("fromday", QString::number(beginQDate.day()));
    ~~~~~~ ^
../src/prices/priceGetterTSP.cpp:89:12: error: no member named 'addQueryItem' in 'QUrl'
    params.addQueryItem("fromyear", QString::number(beginQDate.year()));
    ~~~~~~ ^
../src/prices/priceGetterTSP.cpp:90:12: error: no member named 'addQueryItem' in 'QUrl'
    params.addQueryItem("tomonth", QString::number(endQDate.month()));
    ~~~~~~ ^
../src/prices/priceGetterTSP.cpp:91:12: error: no member named 'addQueryItem' in 'QUrl'
    params.addQueryItem("today", QString::number(endQDate.day()));
    ~~~~~~ ^
../src/prices/priceGetterTSP.cpp:92:12: error: no member named 'addQueryItem' in 'QUrl'
    params.addQueryItem("toyear", QString::number(endQDate.year()));
    ~~~~~~ ^
7 errors generated.
make: *** [priceGetterTSP.o] Error 1
16:40:22: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project mypersonalindex (kit: Desktop Qt 5.8.0 clang 64bit)

**OK ... so what is the replacement?**

What's the missing #include <   >?

Comment: Take a look at the new [QUrlQuery](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qurlquery.html) class.

Comment: @MrEricSir Thanks,  **My C++ skill is pretty limited, do you see any minor tweaks that could convert this from Qt4 to Qt5**.  I doubt I have the background to make changes to use QUrlQuery.    I read in the docs:  The following members of class QUrl are obsolete. They are provided to keep old source code working. We strongly advise against using them in new code.  The error is in  (obsolete) void addQueryItem(const QString &key, const QString &value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of calling `addQueryItem` on a `QUrl` object, you create a `QUrlQuery` object and make the calls on that.
Then you set the finished query on the url

```
QUrlQuery paramsQuery;
paramsQuery.addQueryItem("fund", properCaseSymbol);
// and so on..

params.setQuery(paramsQuery);
```

Since you are not using `params` as an URL but just as a `toString` helper, you could even try just changing the type

```
QUrlQuery params;
```

and keeping most of the code the way it is